# beamertheme.sty not found using TexLive

Tags: beamer, pdftex, texlive, windows

I'm currently trying to install the beamer style called '[Frederiksberg](https://github.com/cbourjau/frederiksberg_beamer)' used for the University of Copenhagen. Their manual states:

1. The directory which in the install package is named tex/latex/beamer/Frederiksberg needs to be put where LATEX will find it.
2. The directory which in the install package is named dvips/Frederiksberg needs to be put where dvips will find it.

I did that:

[image]
[image]

In a .tex file with beamer, I included `\usetheme{Frederiksberg}` according to the manual:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Frederiksberg}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\title[{\fontsize{6}{10}\selectfont \emph{Fysikken bag brint}}]{Fysikken bag brint}
\author[Casper Juul Lorentzen]{Casper Juul Lorentzen}
\institute[3z, HTX]{Albertslund Gymnasium}
\date[Fysik eksamensprojekt]{\today}

\begin{document}


\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Indhold}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduktion}

\begin{frame}{Introduktion}
\begin{center}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Klassisk mekanik vs kvantemekanik \pause 
        \item Klassisk mekanik er en approksimation af verden \pause 
        \item Kvant tager over på atomare skalaer \pause 
        \item Bohr og Schrödinger
    \end{itemize}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and I get the following error:

```
File `beamerthemeFrederiksberg.sty' not found. }
```

I have tried to run the tlmgr.bat file, I have tried to locate the directories not under the 'local' folder but merely under the 'latex' and 'dvips' folders, but I still get the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you run texhash after you placed those files? The description on that github page is very poor.

Comment: You, sir, are a very helpful person. Running texhash worked. Thanks!

Comment: It **is** listed at the bottom of that github page. Because it is so important, it should have been highlighted a lot more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by running texhash.exe as suggested by daleif.